# Visual Studio Xamarin Physical Device Nexus 5X debugging

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to debug with my device 5x a xamarin.forms application, but the device
isn't listed in Visual Studio.

- The Nexus 5 is listed if i use the command "adb devices"
- The Nexus 5 is also listed correctly in the device manager (no errors)
- The device is also listed in the android device monitor.
- I can successful build and deploy an android application in android studio on the device.

But why I cant deploy btw its not shown in Visual Studio.

Thanks for the Help
Lastone

Comment: Is the device physically connected to your Windows machine over USB? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio while keeping the device connected?

Comment: after a certain time it worked I restarted everything but thanks

Comment: Good to hear. Visual Studio often does not recognize an ADB connected device until it has been restarted or unless you connect to the device before opening Visual Studio